# Portrait Image rotated on crop view

Tags: android, android-camera

When I take a picture in portrait mode, the crop view automatically rotates it by 90 degrees. Does not seem to happen in landscape. Is there a way to prevent this

Comment: Do you take the picture in your custom camera app, or you use an Intent?

Comment: @Alex : I use Intent

Comment: If this question is still relevant, please note that image capture intent may behave very different on another device, or if the user installs an alternative camera app.

Answer (score -1):

Change the file type from png to jpg

EDIT: Comments from Charles Caldwell, which explain why this answer is correct: "PNG files do not contain EXIF data which includes the rotation information. If the photo is taken as a PNG, switching to JPG could resolve the issue"

Comment: Do you really think this is an answer to OP's question?

Comment: @sufian Actually, yes. Though the person answering should have provided a lot more information as to why. PNG files to not contain EXIF data which includes the rotation information. If the photo is taken as a PNG, switch to JPG could resolve the issue.

Comment: What makes you think that the photo was stored in PNG format?